# Can't figure out razor syntax for my strongly typed view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a strongly typed view where I am trying to display a model when an `id` is passed to my Controller action method.

I am trying to construct a link to each of this models as well.

For the purpose before the beginning of my `foreach` I have an `i=0`, and then I am trying to increase it by 1 using `i++`. The problem is that the the `i++` part doesn't work -- I have always zero as an `id` in my link.  Why?

Can someone help with this?

```
@{
    var i = 0;
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Content)
        </td>
        <td>

            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = i }) 
           i++;
        </td>
    </tr>
        }
    }
```

Comment: Move the `i++;` to after the closing `</tr>`

Comment: Is your `i++` definitely being considered code and not markup?? Try wrapping it in `@()`, e.g. `@(i++)`

Comment: Sorry I mean `@{}` - the `@()` I believe outputs to HTML which you probably don't want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Razor does its best to distinguish code from markup/html/text, which isn't easy in general. And in this case, `i++` is considered text.

The reason is that there are tags following the `foreach {` part, causing the reading mode to switch to markup/html/text. In that mode only `@...`, `@{...` or `}` are recognized as code, and everything else is treated as markup/html/text.

If this happens, just put `@{ ... }` around your statements, like this:

```
<td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = i }) 
    @{
        i++;
    }
</td>
```